# Is there any option to add a default value to all @RequestHeaders in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, header, request-headers

Is there any option to add a default value to all `@RequestHeader`'s in spring boot?

`@RequestHeader(value = "User-Accept-Language", defaultValue = "en-IN") String localeCd`

I am copy/pasting to all the API's. Any help to avoid code duplication!!

Comment: You can use a filter

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find anything already done for having an annotation for adding a header with a value so I did my own. Here is the code, is very simple, I did it using spring AOP

1. I created the annotation classes

   ```
   import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
   import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
   import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
   import java.lang.annotation.Target;

   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
   public @interface ResponseHeader {

       public String key() default "";

       public String value() default "";
   }
   ```

   and the one for containing an array of Headers annotations

   ```
   import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
   import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
   import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
   import java.lang.annotation.Target;


   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
   public @interface ResponseHeaders {

       public ResponseHeader[] headers();
   }
   ```
2. The AOP class for catching the restControllers (you can customise the AOP for setting you own pointcut as you wish:

   ```
   import YOUR_PACKAGE_ANNOTATION.ResponseHeaders;
   import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
   import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
   import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
   import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
   import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import java.util.List;

   /**
    * Aspect for inserting headers on the methods of the @RestController         
    annotated classes
    */
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class ResponseHeadersAnnotation {

    /**
    * Pointcut for filtering just classes with @RestController annotation
    */
   @Pointcut("@within(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)")
   public void restControllerClass() {
   }

   /**
    * It adds the headers to the response of the method of the controller
    *
    * @param responseHeaders
    */
   @After("restControllerClass() && @annotation(responseHeaders)")
   public void addHeaders(final ResponseHeaders responseHeaders) {
       final HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();
       List.of(responseHeaders.headers()).forEach(responseHeader -> response.setHeader(responseHeader.key(), responseHeader.value()));
    }
   }
   ```
3. Here is an example of how to use it in a controller:

   ```
   @GetMapping(value = {"/ServiceTicketCollection", "/ServiceRequestCollection"})
   @ResponseHeaders(headers = {
           @ResponseHeader(key = "cookie1", value = "value1"),
           @ResponseHeader(key = "cookie2, value = "value2")
   })
   public Object restControllerMethod() {
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This is an example on how to provide a default value for a header using spring WebFlux

```
@Component
public class CorrelationIdFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        var correlationId = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER);
        if (correlationId == null || correlationId.isEmpty()) {
            correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            ServerHttpRequest mutatedRequest = exchange.getRequest()
                    .mutate()
                    .header(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER, correlationId)
                    .build();
            exchange = exchange
                    .mutate()
                    .request(mutatedRequest)
                    .build();
        }
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER, correlationId);
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

And this is for Spring web

```
@Component
public class CorrelationIdFilter implements Filter {

    static final String CORRELATION_ID_HEADER = "X-Correlation-ID";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // empty
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String correlationId = httpRequest.getHeader(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER);
        if (correlationId == null) {
           correlationId = XidFactory.nextXid();
           ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER, correlationId);
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // empty
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to use OncePerRequestFilter and skip filtering if you already have a header

Comment: I am getting `[org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Missing request header 'User-Accept-Language' for method parameter of type String] ` exception

Comment: Check to see if the filter is executed. If you have that error, then, most likely, the filter is not executed. Also you can follow @EugeneMakarenko advice and you can convert this filter to OncePerRequestFilter. For this, all  you have to do is to extend your filter from OncePerRequestFilter and to implement the method doFilterInternal

Comment: wrong example, because question was about request header, not response